# Ag-grid prevent horizontal scroll when resizing screen

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I've got `(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"`

```
        this.grid = params;
        this.grid.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
```

In my component, which fits columns to fit when grid is loaded. However when resizing screen I get horizontal scroll from time to time which is extremely annoying if there are only couple of rows, because it hides data. Is it possible to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your css:

```
.grid {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```